# How to remove value from array json php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a sample code:

```
$json_encode = '{"OS":"Android","Title":"Galaxy"}';
$json_decode = json_decode($json_encode);
foreach($json_decode as $key => $value) {
   if($key == 'Title') {
       unset($key); 
   }
}
print_r(json_encode($json_decode));
```

But result can't `remove key='Title'` from that json string, how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need those extra lines of code, if the `Title` index comes always, then you can unset the `Title` index directly :

```
$json_encode = '{"OS":"Android","Title":"Galaxy"}';
$json_decode = json_decode($json_encode);
unset($json_decode['Title']);
```

See the link below for more information on PHP Array **Unset** function, you are making mistake on simple syntax.

[PHP Array Unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include the array in the `unset` statement. It should be:

```
unset($json_decode[$key]);
```

Actually, for your particular example, you don't even need a loop, you can unset the value directly.

Also to get an associative array from the `json_encode` function, you need to add another parameter:

```
$json_decode = json_decode($json_encode, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$json_decode = json_decode($json_encode,TRUE);
```

If "TRUE" is not passed, json_decode returns an object.

Also replace `unset($key)` with `unset($json_decode[$key]);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$json_encode = '{"OS":"Android","Title":"Galaxy"}';
$json_decode = json_decode($json_encode, true);
foreach ($json_decode as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array('Title', $value)) {
        unset($json_decode[$key]);
    }
}
$json_encode = json_encode($json_decode);
```